# Changing SSH Password which is routing through mysql

Tags: mysql

I have mysql root username and password with me and i am on centos server. I know how to login through putty to the mysql panel.

I am in. we are also connecting the mysql through Navicat and it accepts the SSH connection to the mysql server even we do provide the username / password because the server is not directly linked.

So, what is the possibility that i can change the Password of the SSH which is doing the mysql connectivity through navicat.

how can i use the command console panel to change the SSH to change it

Please do not vote for negative as if the question is not clear, ask me before downvoting

Regards

Comment: Waht are you trying to do?

Comment: Don't use passwords.  ssh auth via public key.

Comment: We are connecting to database server which is not directly accessible, so they gave me credentials and ssh details to login into db, now when we do the navicat, i get password authentication failed error

Comment: i solved it guys! Thanks, Let me close this now

Comment: lol... Anyway the Q'n keeps confused... :P

Answer (score 0):

So, Here is the Solution.

When i was logging into putty, i was doing the ssh using my username and password, the same credentials i used in navicat and bang it worked, so there was no need to change the credentials, i already got it connected to my database, sory about the confusion, hopefully one should never encounter this issue, for me it was hard to debug as i was very new to centos operating system